# How can you aggregate a single column based all the other columns?

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a large number of CSV files that contain survey data. As a result I know that there is a good deal of duplicated data. Thus, I want to summarize the data by finding the frequency of unique responses. Typically I do this by inserting a frequency column with a value of one and then summing it. Like so:

```
data = aggregate(data$Freq, by = list(ONE = data$ONE, TWO = data$TWO, THREE  = data$THREE), FUN = sum)
```

In this case that approach is not feasible since the column names are not consistent and are variable in number. Sample data looks like what the following generates:

```
data = data.frame(
   ONE   = sample(1:2, 40, TRUE), 
   TWO   = sample(1:2, 40, TRUE),
   THREE = sample(1:5, 40, TRUE)); 
data$Freq = 1
```

How can I preserve the unique values and find the count of their appearance?

Comment: Any chance of a little sample data set to save us making up our own?

Comment: `data = data.frame(ONE=sample(LETTERS[1:4],20,TRUE), TWO=sample(LETTERS[1:4],20,TRUE)); data$Freq=1` ?

Comment: @Spacedman Factors. I've cleaned them up so that they are either [0, 1] or [1, 5] based upon valid survey responses.

Comment: Something like this, maybe: `library(tidyverse); data %>% select(-Freq) %>% group_by_all() %>% tally`. I've removed the `Freq` column because you don't need it for this approach.

Comment: You could use the formula interface with `aggregate` like this: `aggregate(Freq ~ ., data=data, sum)`. The dot means "every other variable."

Comment: Just out of curiosity, even if you have two rows of data with the exact same responses, how can you tell that both rows came from the same respondent (i.e., that they are really duplicates rather than two different survey responses that happen to have the same answers)?

Comment: @lmo That works perfectly! I thought there was some sort of way of doing it in `aggregate` and was tearing through the manual to find it.

Comment: @eipi10 Getting the count of similar responses from all the respondents is what I'm trying to do. I pretty much have to assume there is no duplication of data from the people that coded the responses.

Comment: As a second alternative, using the direct interface from your question, you could use `grep` like `aggregate(data$Freq, by = data[-grep("Freq", names(data))], FUN = sum)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it without creating the Freq=1 variable, you can create that "on the fly":

```
> head(data)
  ONE TWO THREE
1   D   D     C
2   A   B     C
3   C   B     D
4   A   A     D
5   A   B     A

> aggregate(rep(1,nrow(data)) ~ ., data=data, sum)

   ONE TWO THREE rep(1, nrow(data))
1    B   A     A                  1
2    C   A     A                  3
3    D   A     A                  2
4    A   B     A                  1
5    D   B     A                  1
```

But it does give a rough name to the column. Wrap it in `setNames`:

```
> setNames(aggregate(rep(1,nrow(data)) ~ ., data=data, sum), c(names(data),"Freq"))
   ONE TWO THREE Freq
1    B   A     A    1
2    C   A     A    3
3    D   A     A    2
4    A   B     A    1
5    D   B     A    1
```

Comment: Or you could use `cbind` to add the name like this `aggregate(cbind(Freq=rep(1,nrow(data))) ~ ., data=data, sum)`.